# Scope using an argument and accessing many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, many-to-many

Hello I am having issues working with a rails relations.

I have the follow to classes, I want to be able to pass an argument to a method or a scope and return the whatever Resources have products equal the argument.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title

  has_and_belongs_to_many :resources   
end


class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  scope :has_product, ->(product) { joins(:products).where(products: { title: product }) }

  #OR

  def self.has_product(product)
    self.products.each do |p|
      return self if p.title == product 
    end
  end
end

class Report < Resource
end
```

ERROR

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_product' for #<Report:0x007fa859aa3080>
from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
```

Please help me see what I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `products` as a class method, because it's instance method (usage: `Resource.last.products`) . So that, the same applies to `has_product?` method:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  def has_product?(product)
    product_ids.include?(product.id)
  end

end
```

Usage:

```
product = Product.first
Resource.last.has_product?(product) # => true or false
```

**Edit:**

To answer the question, to get whatever resources has given product use scope, e.g:

```
scope :for_product, ->(product) { joins(:products).where(products: { title: product.title }) }
```

Usage:

```
product = Product.first
Resource.for_product(product) # => ActiveRecord::Relation with products
```

Comment: is it possible to pass an array of strings instead of a string?

Comment: Yep, it might be an array of products. Then, the scope would be: `scope :for_products, ->(products) { joins(:products).where(products: { id: products }) }`. You can use it either as `Resource.for_products(Product.first)` (for particular product) or `Resource.for_products(Product.limit(5))` (an array).